# How to Create class using object from another class

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have class coordinate that has 2 attribute: `Long`, `Lat`.

Then how can I create class polygon that has one or more object of class `Coordinat`?

```
class Coordinat:
    def __init__(self, id, Lat, Long):
        self.id=id
        self.Lat=Lat
        self.Long=Long
```

Then how do I create class polygon?

Comment: Which Python version are you using? Please tag either python 2 or python 3.

Comment: remove how to from you're question and you've your answer in python docs

Comment: @AvinashRaj Would you care to explain how exactly a polygon would be a "kind of" coordinate ???  The relationship _explicitely_ asked for by the OP is "has a" (and in this case "has a set of"), not "is a".

Answer (score 0):

> how to create a class using object from another class

Well, that's already what you're doing in your "Coordinat" class: it does use three "objects from another class" for `id`, `Lat` and `Long` (which I assume are either an int or string for the first and floats for the second and third). Remember that in Python just everything is an object...

In your case, since a generic polygon doesn't have a fixed number of angles, you want an ordered sequence (`tuple` or `list`) of `Coordinat`:

```
class Polygon(object):
     def __init__(self, **coords):
         self.coords = coords

triangle = Polygon(
    Coordinat(1, 42.5, 4.5), 
    Coordinat(2, 85.4, 77.2), 
    Coordinat(3, 99.1, 42.2)
    )
```

Comment: i use your way, but how a access lat and long from one of coordinat... for example i wanna to calculate distance between coordinat of triangle...

Comment: what's wrong with `triangle.coords[0].Lat` ? Note that for regular polygon's you'll probably want to have specific classes...

Comment: I use your way again. But another error when i  set value to the object of polygon.
my code :  'point = []
    point.append(Coordinat(1, 22,33))
    point.append(Coordinat(2, 45,66))
    Polygon(id,distance, point)'
error :Polygon(id,distance, point))
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)

Comment: the error is __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)

Comment: @ErnaPiantari perhaps you should re-read the error message __and__ the __full__ traceback...  It usually contains enough informations to find out what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you should use Inheritance, you can have a look at the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance).

In your case you could do something like this:

```
class Coordinat:
    def __init__(self, id, Lat, Long):
        self.id=id
        self.Lat=Lat
        self.Long=Long

class Polygon(Coordinat):
    def __init__(self, id, Lat, Long, prop1, prop2)
        #Call __init__ method from base class to have id, Lat and Long   initialized
        Coordinat.__init__(id, Lat, Long)
        #Initiailze the other properties
        self.prop1 = prop1
        self.prop2 = prop2
        ...
```